# atomic boolean usage/implementation in C++98

Tags: c++, atomic, c++98

I have been looking everywhere for a solid answer and even found someone attempting to write their own implementation.  But does anyone know of something similar to the `std::atomic<bool>` for C++98?  I just need `true/false` values.

No flame wars or asking me to upgrade please.  The boards we are using are forcing us to use C++98.

Comment: Which platform/compiler ? intrinsic might exist...

Comment: Do you need it to be portable?  Have you checked boost?

Comment: At worst, a non lock-free atomic might be implemented with mutex...

Comment: You simply can't do it in a pure C/C++. Earlier standards simply had no notion of multithreading, it's not in their memory model.

If it's the boards you are using - find out if the boards themselves have any kind of support lib. Maybe there is already atomic available. If not, check if HW support atomic operations. Maybe you'll have to resort to inline asm, but it's not hard. Especially for a simple limited case.

Comment: You can make one of your architecture has a test-and-set instruction.

Comment: Yeah, no boost either.  Was hoping to have a raw C++ implementation.  As far as portability, kind of.  Running on x86 Linux boxes and Motorola XXX Mercury boards.

Comment: On X86, `volatile` is sometimes used in C++98 code to support atomic loads and stores (with relaxed memory ordering) for types that are atomic on CPU level (`bool` usually is). You cannot perform atomic RMW's on a `volatile bool` with standard C++98